# How to turn a Git project into runable databricks notebook?

Tags: r, azure-devops, rstudio, databricks, azure-databricks

After having developed an R project in RStudio Server on Azure which is tracked using Git, I need to execute the whole project in a databricks notebook.

Thereby, the main.R is sourcing further functions from the different folders of the project.

I am wondering what the best way is to import the project to databricks notebooks avoiding to turn all functions into single notebooks. Is it possible to source them all at once?

Answer (score 0):

Databricks notebook provide the facility to execute the code exist in other notebooks.

Eg: I have created a new notebook 'MyNotebookName' having application utils and place it under a folder 'MyFolderName'.
[image: folder screenshot]
From the other notebook exist in other folder 'MyFolderName', I can call the MyNotebookName2 from the MyNotebookName.

Below is the command to call the notebook from another notebook.

`%run "/MyFolderName/MyNotebookName"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know about that possibility. However, it would require me to copy-paste all the code from the Git repo into notebook that -in turn- can then be sourced by the "main notebook". Not only due to maintanance reasons, I would rather like to get the whole Git repo into databricks and execute the main. I guess we must build an R package that is automatically deployed via e.g. devops.

Comment: that even I don't know... I will suggest you to update the tags also so that more people can reach out to you. eg: azure-databricks, databricks